# Ruby class extension in Rails works when declared locally, returns `nil` when imported from `/lib/`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, class-extensions

TLDR: A hash extension works flawlessly, returning the desired output, when included locally in my Mailer, but always returns `nil` when imported from a module in `lib/`, even though the class method is successfully loaded.

When I declare the extension in my mailer.rb file, before my class definition, as in:

```
class Hash
  def try_deep(*fields)
    ...
  end
end

class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  some_hash.try_deep(:some_key)
end
```

it works flawlessly, but this is bad practice. I thought it better to declare the extension in `/lib/core_ext/hash/try_deep.rb` and then require it in the Mailer, as in:

**/lib/core_ext/hash/try_deep.rb:**

```
module CoreExtensions
  module Hash
    module TryDeep
      def try_deep(*fields)
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**/my_mailer.rb:**

```
require 'core_ext/hash/try_deep'

class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  Hash.include CoreExtensions::Hash::TryDeep
  some_hash.try_deep(:some_key)
end
```

Comment: Side question: Are you implementing [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-dig)?

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej Good question. The reason I'm implementing this is to be able to safely dig for attributes in a mixed-object-version environment. Older objects are missing certain newer attributes. Hash#dig, while it seems great at first, doesn't solve my problem because it throws an error rather than 'nil' when it digs for a key that doesn't exist. For my idiosyncratic use-case (sending an email), 'nil' is what I want when a key isn't found.

Comment: It seems to return `nil` to me when a key does not exist: `{a: 1}.dig(:b) => nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject your custom method into `Hash` outside of your class:

**my_mailer.rb**:

```
require 'core_ext/hash/try_deep'

class Hash
  include CoreExtensions::Hash::TryDeep
end

class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  some_hash.try_deep(:some_key)
end
```